# Passing Parameters into Google Site Iframe Gadget

Tags: google-sites, google-sites-2016

I'm trying to embed multiple items into a (new version) google site that take a parameter from another embed.

Is there any way to do this in new (not classic) google sites?

For more background:
We have one Tableau workbook that includes parameters the user can select.  These selected parameters drive a handful of other unrelated Tableau workbooks and SSRS reports, all of which need to be on the same page.

It doesn't matter whether the user can select their parameters on the first page and then get driven to a second page with all the additional workbooks or whether the workbooks are all on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

New Google Sites insert content from other site feature requires a URL but at this time there is no way to take a parameter from another inserted content.

As usual there is no official documentation on the [official help](https://support.google.com/sites) about not available features. The related help article is [Add text, images, & other content](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/6372879?hl=en).